# conditional sorting using order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, case-when

While sorting based on condition in procedure:

```
    ...
    SELECT 
    ...
    order by formattedbookingdate 
    CASE WHEN isasc IS TRUE THEN
    asc
    ELSE
    desc
    END;
    ...
```

Postgres throws error:
**ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 266: CASE WHEN isasc IS TRUE THEN**

Comment: You can't create dynamic SQL like that. What type of column is `formattedbookingdate`?

Comment: formattedbookingdate is of type timestamp

Comment: @VishnuGS hopefully `isac` is not a column? :)

Comment: Nope isasc is a variable in procedure

Answer (score 1):

I would separate conditions, so you add `asc` or `desc` after end, like:

```
td=# select * from (select generate_series(1,3) a) a order by case when true then a end asc, case when true then a end desc;
 a
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)

td=# select * from (select generate_series(1,3) a) a order by case when false then a end asc, case when true then a end desc;
 a
---
 3
 2
 1
(3 rows)
```

And yes, I would think again on why I would do that :)

Comment: In case you have a pretty large select statement, procedure becomes bulky

Answer (score 1):

This probably is gonna be slow but it works:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    order by
    CASE WHEN isasc IS TRUE THEN
    formattedbookingdate
    ELSE
    TIMESTAMP 'epoch' - formattedbookingdate
    END;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2469)